# Whoa! The search results just gave me a book!

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

So, the latest question here on Meta prompted me to do a quick search for ["code review"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22code%20review%22). Everything looked all fine and dandy until I switched to the **votes** tab, where I was prompted with this nice book of text on my screen:

> [image: A trip to the library]
>   [<sub>Click here for expanded version.</sub>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhoKe.jpg)

What did I break? **o.o** I'm pretty sure I'm not supposed to be presented with *that much* text.

Comment: Not sure that the FAQ portion about books applies here or not.

Comment: Just lucky with the sort order. If you look at the other sorts, the particular questions look just as bookish.

Comment: Initial tests point to a bug in elasticsearch here - I'll try and pin it down.

Comment: @Nick any updates? Reproduced by searching for "Stack Overflow" if it's of any help.

Comment: We just encountered this [on Maths.SE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10988/43351) as well.

Comment: Encountered this on SO by using [this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=body%3a%22same+problem%22) then clicking to the last page of results and iterating backward.

Comment: still happening after the [last elasticsearch upgrade](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b0U5KaWzDKE)

Comment: Looks like it's fixed now...? http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22code%20review%22

Comment: Is [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290480/why-does-the-preview-in-this-search-results-take-up-so-much-space) related? @Nick

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Closing the loop on this - indeed Elastic did nasty, terrible, evil, unconscionable, unspeakable things that scared young children, horrified the bravest of us, and made it hard to sleep at night and...wait, no, it still does all those things.

The snippet length crazy was fixed in a subsequent upgrade though.