# Why does the preview in this search results take up so much space?

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

I did a search on the [Programming Puzzles and Code-Golf StackExchange](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) and I noticed that one of the answers took up way more space than all of the others.  In particular [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108323/56656) takes up three pages (on my browser)

[Link to the search](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=brain%20flak)

Images for when the search becomes outdated:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

Why does this particular answer take up so much space while similar answers do not?  Is this a bug? Since it is my answer how might I edit this to avoid this showing up and bothering people?

Comment: I guess it's counting words, not characters, and since there's no space in this code (?) it's being counted as a single word.

Comment: Cross-site dupe of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327327/abnormally-long-summaries-in-search

Comment: Might be the same bug as [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174399/whoa-the-search-results-just-gave-me-a-book), which appears to not be really fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed in a later Elastic upgrade to 5.x (same as [Whoa! The search results just gave me a book!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174399/whoa-the-search-results-just-gave-me-a-book/321909#321909)).